# Initializing FinancialData indices .... never finishes

Tags: bugs, curated-data, windows, finance

**Bug introduced in 10.3.0 and fixed in 10.3.1**

---

Retrieving data using [`FinancialData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html) became more unreliable in the last couple of months, but simply retrying was enough to finally get the data. Now it seems to be nearly completely broken in *Mathematica* v10.3 under Windows 10. However, it is still working fine in v9.0.1.

In the following GIF v9.0.1 is on the left side and v10.3 is on the right side.
[image: GIF]

```
FinancialData["SPY", "Price"]

FinancialData["^VIX", "Price"]
```

Is this malfunction reproducible with your v10.3 installation or is it limited to mine?
**With what settings can I make retrieving data using `FinancialData` in v10.3 working and more reliable?**

```
PacletFind["*FinancialData*"]
```

returns

> `{Paclet["FinancialData_Symbols_Y3","7.1.15",<>]}`

in version 9.0.1 and

> `{Paclet["FinancialData_Symbols_Y3","10.1.19",<>]}`

in version 10.3.

---

Other `*Data` functions seem to be affected, too. For example

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Temperature"]
```

will never show anything if it doesn't work.
[image: NOTworking]

However, after a couple of retries it worked, showing some initializations. In such a situation `FinancialData` also does work. Unfortunately, after restarting *Mathematica* it failed again and again.

[image: Working]

I don't witness any problems using

```
Entity["Financial", "^VIX"][EntityProperty["Financial", "Last"]]
```

---

Deleting the *pacletSiteData_10.pmd2* file, as described in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101339/initializing-financialdata-indices-never-finishes#comment275291_101339) by [FredrikD](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1635/fredrikd) provides a temporary workaround. It is enough to restart the kernel after deleting that file, but unfortunately after another kernel restart retrieving data is broken again. 
[image: GIFDemonstration]

Comment: Both work fine for me. MMA 10.3 on OSX 10.10.5

Comment: There is also no problem using the [Wolfram Development Platform](https://develop.wolframcloud.com), which is version `10.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)`. Adding the [tag:windows] tag.

Comment: Are you on the most recent version of Java?

Comment: @PeterRoberge Yes, Version 8 Update 66.

Comment: @PeterRoberge `ShowJavaConsole[]` shows `J/Link version 4.9.0
Java version 1.7.0_13  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`.

Comment: @Karsten7. How about other web operations? Have you tried using `Import` to grab a yahoo finance page?

Comment: @PeterRoberge `Import["http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SPY", "Data"][[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3 ;; 4]]` returning `{{"Bid:", "209.59 x 200"}, {"Ask:", "209.60 x 100"}}`, no problems.

Comment: `CalendarData` hanging in Mma 10.3 on Windows 10.  Can work if it's the first thing called.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks for checking. `CalendarData[]` also just returns `Initializing CalendarData indices ....` for me. What do you mean with "Can work if it's the first thing called."?

Comment: @Karsten7. - It sometimes works if the first thing run is `CalendarData[]`, but it's intermittent.

Comment: @Karsten7. I've got V.10.3 Win 10. No problem. Got `207.809, 16.69`, Fast, not flick; Weather data works slow but gives 3.3 C. Your last code gives `Quantity[16.83, "USDollars"]`. Note `$` added.

Comment: @garej Thanks for checking. I just tried it again myself and it worked. Restarted *Mathematica*, tried again and it failed. It would be nice if you could try `FinancialData["SPY", "Price"]` two times, restarting *Mathematica* in between. What does `PacletFind["*FinancialData*"]` return?

Comment: @Karsten7. I've tried in different combinations - it works fine (sometimes faster or slower). Your last request returns output '{
PacletManager`Paclet[
 "Name" -> "FinancialData_Symbols_Y3", "Version" -> "10.1.19", 
  "MathematicaVersion" -> "10.0+", "BackwardCompatible" -> "*", 
  "Extensions" -> {{
    "Resource", "Root" -> "Data", 
     "Resources" -> {"FinancialData_Symbols_Y3.wdx"}}}, 
  "Location" -> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\\
Paclets\\Repository\\FinancialData_Symbols_Y3-10.1.19"]}'

Comment: Works for me (Win8.1-64, MMA 10.3).

Comment: When this happens with my Wolfram Desktop Producer, I remove the "pacletSiteData_10.pmd2" file from C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\WolframDesktop\Paclets\Configuration Restart the computer, Wolfram recreates the file and then it works. Seems to be a bug that is related to initializing the system. Not only for FinancialData, also sometimes for other curated data

Comment: @FredrikD Thanks a lot for that very helpful comment. Restarting the computer isn't necessary. It is enough to restart the *Mathematica* kernel.

Comment: I found this question because I'm trying to find out why I get this error: `FinancialData::notent: ^VIX is not a known entity, class, or tag for FinancialData. Use FinancialData[] for a list of entities.`

Comment: @Michael It seems like Mathematica doesn't know `^VIX` anymore. It's not in `Select[FinancialData[], StringMatchQ["*VIX*"]]`. You should contact Wolfram support about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in 10.3.1

---

It seems to be fixed in 10.3.1. Not able to reproduce it. Windows 7, 64 bit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

And the weather data also works. (it takes few seconds to read all the data)

[image]

Comment: Where you able to reproduce it with version 10.3. It is fixed also for me with version 10.3.1, but I used that update as an opportunity to reset my *Mathematica* installation and wanted to see if it keeps working. With version 10.3 it wasn't completely broken, but got worse and worse.

Comment: @Karsten7.  When I installed 10.3.1 I removed 10.3, so I do not know if it worked or not in 10.3 now.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary workaround based on the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101339/initializing-financialdata-indices-never-finishes#comment275291_101339) by [FredrikD](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1635/fredrikd) is to start any new notebook, in which a `*Data` function will be used with

```
DeleteFile[
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBasePacletsDirectory, "Configuration", "pacletSiteData_10.pmd2"}]];
Quit
```

and to add

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" -> False];     

DeleteFile[
  FileNameJoin[{$UserBasePacletsDirectory, "Configuration", "pacletSiteData_10.pmd2"}]];
Quit
```

to the beginning of every notebook that contains a `*Data` function and is supposed to work reliably when evaluated as a whole. (Reference for the option setting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13740555)

During the restart of the kernel *pacletSiteData_10.pmd2* will be recreated and *managerData_10.3.0.0.pmd2* will be updated.

Comment: Great ref to the Stackoverflow question. Didn't know that was possible